# Range hours 30 minutes (or 20 minutes) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time, range

I need to calculate the range between two hours JavaScript, example:

```
var calculeHor = 30; // or 20, or 15, or 10...
var horIni = "8:30";
var horEnd = "13:00";
```

The result is:

```
var range = [
    {08:30 - 09:00}, 
    {09:00 - 09:30}, 
    {09:30 - 10:00}, 
    {10:00 - 10:30}, 
    {10:30 - 11:00}, 
    {11:00 - 11:30}, 
    {11:30 - 12:00}, 
    {12:00 - 12:30}, 
    {12:30 - 13:00}
];
```

Comment: Thanks, do not know if I explained well, but the idea is to have an object with the preamble of hours defined between 20 or 30 minutes, so you get the result as in the example.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: One way is to convert the time to the lowest common denominator, minutes here, do the subtraction, then convert back to hours. The *rage* array seems to contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it:

```js
function time(start, end, interval) {
    let s = start.split(':').map(e => +e);
    let e = end.split(':').map(e => +e);
    let res = [];
    let h_prev = s[0];
    let m_prev = s[1];

    while (h_prev < e[0] || m_prev < e[1]) {
        s[1] += interval;
        if (s[1] > 59) {
            s[0] += 1;
            s[1] %= 60;
        }
        if (s[0] < e[0] || s[1] <= e[1])
            res.push(h_prev + ':' + (m_prev < 10 ? '0' + m_prev : m_prev) + " - " + s[0] + ':' + (s[1] < 10 ? '0' + s[1] : s[1]));

        h_prev = s[0];
        m_prev = s[1];

        if (h_prev == e[0] && e[1] - m_prev < interval) break;

    }
    return res;
}

console.log(time('8:30', '13:00', 30));
console.log(time('23:00', '23:30', 30));
console.log(time('23:00', '23:31', 30));
```

Comment: It doesn't work if "end" is half-hour....can you confirm?

Comment: @EdoardoVignati Yes, It can't work with "next" day

Comment: This will trigger an infinite loop if you pass `time('23:00','23:30', 30)`

Comment: @Indraraj26 check it now

Answer (score 3):

That should do it:

```js
function getRange(start, end, interval) {
    function getMinutes(time) {
        var a = time.split(':').map(Number);
        return a[0] * 60 + a[1];
    }

    function getTime(m) {
        var h = m / 60 | 0;
        m %= 60;
        return h + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m);
    }

    var r = [],
        startM = getMinutes(start),
        endM = getMinutes(end);

    while (startM + interval <= endM) {
        r.push(getTime(startM) + ' - ' + getTime(startM + interval));
        startM += interval;
    }
    return r;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getRange('8:30', '13:00', 30), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getRange('9:20', '11:00', 20), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The test `if (startM + interval > endM) ` is redundant. Without it, if it's true then the function returns an empty array rather than *undefined* (which is likely a better outcome). ;-)